# Desired output calculation wrong?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, logic, output

I've written this program but am running into a logical error upon compilation.

My input would be `1, 2, 6, 10` for the selection of products and the coinciding output should be

```
Total items ordered: 3
Price of items ordered: $747.00
Sales Tax: $48.55
Total amount due: $795.55
```

Strangely enough it is giving me

```
Total items ordered: 3
Price of items ordered: $6611.00
Sales Tax: $429.715
Total amount due: $7040.715
```

Is there an error within my for loop conditions or calculations, or my array that is leading to this hyper-inflated output?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class GrapefruitOrderingArray {

//Declare Constants 
public static final int SIZE = 100;
public static final int[] itemPrices = {49,299,329,399,199,1299,1199,999,599};  

public static void main(String[] args) {
// Declare Variables
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);                                    
    String CustomerName;                                                       
    int[] naNumber = new int [SIZE];                                            
    int nProducts = 0;                                                        
    double nTotal = 0;                                                          
    double dFinalPrice = 0.0;                                                   
    int nCount = 0;                                                             

    //Declare Constants 
    final int SENTINEL = 10;   
    final double SALES_TAX = 0.065;

    //Prompt user to enter name
    System.out.println("Please enter your name: ");

    //Enter user name
    CustomerName = input.nextLine();

    System.out.println("");

    //Begin Product Listing Declarations with respect to array above
    System.out.println("GRAPEFRUIT PRODUCT:");
    System.out.println("1. gPod shuffle $" + itemPrices[0]);
    System.out.println("2. gPod Touch   $" + itemPrices[1]);
    System.out.println("3. gPad Mini    $" + itemPrices[2]);
    System.out.println("4. gPad 2       $" + itemPrices[3]);
    System.out.println("5. gPhone       $" + itemPrices[4]);
    System.out.println("6. gMac         $" + itemPrices[5]);
    System.out.println("7. MacNovel Pro $" + itemPrices[6]);
    System.out.println("8. MacNovel Air $" + itemPrices[7]);
    System.out.println("9. MiniMac      $" + itemPrices[8]);
    System.out.println("10. Complete my order");

    //Keep reading until the input is terminated by sentinel
    System.out.println("\nPlease select an item from the menu above: ");

    //Read number entered by the user
    naNumber[nCount] = input.nextInt();

    //Begin while-loop statement
    while (naNumber[nCount] != SENTINEL) {

    System.out.println("\nPlease select another item from the menu above: ");

    nCount++;

    //Read number entered by the user
    naNumber[nCount] = input.nextInt();
 }  

    System.out.println("Thank you for ordering with Grapefruit Company, " + CustomerName);
        //Call final price calculation
        dFinalPrice = calculateTotalPrice(naNumber,itemPrices,nTotal);

            //Print blank line to screen
            System.out.println("");

            //Total amount of product ordered
            System.out.println("Total items ordered: " + nCount );

            //Total price of items ordered
            System.out.println("Price of items ordered: $" + dFinalPrice );

            //Sales tax associated with the purchase
            System.out.println("Sales tax: $" + SALES_TAX * dFinalPrice );

            //Total amount due by the customer to Grapefruit Co. 
            System.out.println("Total amount due: $" + (SALES_TAX * dFinalPrice + dFinalPrice ));
    } //End main method

 private static double calculateTotalPrice(int[] naNumber, int[] itemPrices) {

  double total = 0;

  //Calculate entered items
  for(int i = 0; i < naNumber.length; i++){
   if(naNumber[i] != 0) {
   total += itemPrices[naNumber[i] - 1];
  }
}

  return total;
  }
} //end class calculateTotalPriceOfItemsOrdered
```

Comment: You also should not use floating point for money, ever. I would suggest using the BigDecimal class to calculate the sales tax, but the calculation could be done with integer math, representing dollar values as a whole number of cents. Floating point money will only lead to trouble.

Comment: It would also probably be easier if you stored the user's selections in an `ArrayList<Integer>` instead of an array. You wouldn't have to worry about excluding zeroes since the only items in the list would be ones the user chose, and you could handle more than 100 purchases.

Answer (score 0):

You `naNumber` will contain numbers from 1 to 9. This means that you'll be multiplying the item prices by some large numbers at some points, hence why you're getting large totals.

What I think you want to do is

```
double itemTotal = itemPrices[naNumber[i] - 1];
nTotal += itemTotal;
```

Without multiplying itemPrices[i] by naNumber[i]

Also you don't really need to pass `nTotal` to the method and initialise a `double` with every loop. You can just declare a field outside the loop:

```
double total = 0;
```

Use it inside the loop like this:

```
total += itemPrices[naNumber[i] - 1];
```

And return it at the end of the method.

So your method would look something like that:

```
private static double calculateTotalPrice(int[] naNumber, int[] itemPrices) {

double total = 0;

//Calculate entered items
for(int i = 0; i < naNumber.length; i++){
  if(naNumber[i] != 0) {
  total += itemPrices[naNumber[i] - 1];
  }
}

return total;
}
```

Comment: `itemPrices[i]` is wrong. You are using the loop index to select an item price, instead of the item the user chose.

Comment: Closer. The itemPrices are 0-based, but the naNumbers are 1-based.

Comment: Aah yeah. Edited. Hope it's right now :P. I need to install an IDE :)

Answer (score 0):

There are three problems here.

- You put the sentinel value, 10, into the array of items the user has chosen.
- You use the loop index rather than the number the user chose when calculating price.
- You multiply the price of each item by its number. So the user buys 6 of item 6.

In your `main` method, you need to read the user's input into another variable, and only insert it into the array if it is not the sentinel value.

In your `calculateTotalPrice` method, you should calculate the price of an individual line item like this:

```
double itemTotal = itemPrices[naNumber[i] - 1];
```

Comment: I've edited my code to include the updated loop-control variables and now it is prompting my with `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 9
 at grapefruitorderingarray.GrapefruitOrderingArray.calculateTotalPrice(GrapefruitOrderingArray.java:126)
 at grapefruitorderingarray.GrapefruitOrderingArray.main(GrapefruitOrderingArray.java:94)
Java Result: 1`

Comment: Would you care to elaborate further? It now won't compile without an `OutOfBounds` error?

Comment: That's because you put the sentinel value, 10, into the array. So you have four items, 1, 2, 6, and 10, and it looks up their prices from positions 0, 1, 5, and 9, but `itemPrices[9]` does not exist and throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. As I said above, you need to read the user's input into another variable, and *only insert it into the array **if it is not the sentinel value***.